# R Programming: How to combine stack with line diagram using ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following data set:

```
yr  v1  v2  v3
1   18  17  34
2   23  36  31
3   29  34  30
4   37  16  25
5   31  22  19
```

yr= year/time variable. I want to plot three line diagrams (for v1,v2 and v3). Then introduce three horizontal bands on the plot area to show high/medium,low based on this range:

```
 >= 20 : LOW
 <20 and >= 30 : Medium
 >30: High
```

I used ggplot to proceed like this:

first I stacked all the values in one column and created an  "id" column of "var1",var2", "var3" to get three line diagrams:

test1:

```
yr  values  id
1   18  var1
2   23  var1
3   29  var1
4   37  var1
5   31  var1
1   17  var2
2   36  var2
3   34  var2
4   16  var2
5   22  var2
1   34  var3
2   31  var3
3   30  var3
4   25  var3
5   19  var3


ggplot(data = test1, aes(x = year, y = values, color = id)) + geom_line(aes(group = id)) + geom_point()
```

Next: I created a stacked plot for the range.

I assigned a value 40 to "high", combined all the 3 values in the range (20,30,40). Then I added a new column "name" showing high/medium/low.

test2:

```
yr  values  name
1   20  low
2   20  low
3   20  low
4   20  low
5   20  low
1   30  med
2   30  med
3   30  med
4   30  med
5   30  med
1   40  high
2   40  high
3   40  high
4   40  high
5   40  high

ggplot(data = test2, aes(x = year, y = values, fill = name)) + geom_area(position = 'stack')
```

While these two ggplots work fine individually, I don't know if it's possible to combine them in one plot to get:
The three lines with three horizontal bands in the back ground.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please improve the question. 1) better to use dput to provide the data 2) Its' not clear clear what test2 is. If it is the result of the of the paragraph before it "Next: I created ..." then please provide the code. 

As written you leave too much work just to try and recreate the data

Comment: @epi99 Sorry for not being clear earlier. I will try the answer below. But hope the question now makes more sense.

Comment: its much clearer but still would be better with dput. dput outputs executable code that recreates the data structure. Here is an example of the output from dput 

`structure(list(yr = 1:5, low = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20), medium = c(30, 
30, 30, 30, 30), high = c(40, 40, 40, 40, 40)), .Names = c("yr", 
"low", "medium", "high"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: If you're using `position = "stack"` (the default), you don't really want `30` and `40` for `med` and `high`; that would be the numbers for `position = "identity"` (which works, but makes the colors overlap unpleasantly). To use `"stack"`, you want `20` for `low` and `10` for the other two, because that's how much higher you want them than the last bar. You'll also probably want to turn `name` into a factor with the levels in the appropriate order to get the stacking right.

Comment: Hi @alistaire  followed your way to consider test1 for the line diagrams and test2 for my bands. Ran the following code. It does not give me the nice plot you generated. Could you please tell me where I am wrong :         
           `ggplot(data= test1, aes(year, values, color = id)) +  geom_line() +     geom_point() +  geom_area(data = expand.grid (yr = test2$year,y = test2$values, band = as.factor(test2$name) ), aes(yr, y, color = NULL, fill = band),    alpha = 0.2)`

Comment: `expand.grid` is not making the data.frame you need in that usage; take a look at the results directly. Using dplyr, you could make it like `library(tidyverse); ggplot(data = test1 %>% gather(id, values, -yr), aes(yr, values, color = id)) + geom_area(data = test2 %>% mutate(values = ifelse(name == 'low', 20, 10), band = factor(name, levels = c('high', 'med', 'low'))), aes(yr, values, color = NULL, fill = band), alpha = 0.2) + geom_line() + geom_point()` though you could do the same thing in base if you prefer.

Comment: @alistaire Excellent ! Thanks a lot. Learnt a few things today apart from getting my desired plot.

Answer (score 2):

To plot all the lines at once, you need to gather to long form so you can pass all the variables to the `y` aesthetic as one. To plot the bands from a separate data.frame, you'll need to pass `geom_area` a new data parameter and aesthetic mapping instead of relying on the inherited one.

Without `test2` this is an approximation, but all together, roughly,

```
library(tidyr)    # for `gather`
library(ggplot2)

test1 %>% gather(variable, value, -yr) %>%    # gather to long form
    ggplot(aes(yr, value, color = variable)) + 
    geom_area(data = expand.grid(yr = test1$yr,    # new data.frame for bands
                                 y = 10, 
                                 band = c('very low', 'low', 'medium', 'high')), 
              aes(yr, y, color = NULL, fill = band),    # new aesthetic for bands
              alpha = 0.2) + 
    geom_line() + geom_point()    # these can inherit aes from ggplot
```

[image: multi-line plot with bands]